# PHP string remove multi -- for rewrite url

Tags: php

i have a string example: "over-80---of-international----visitors-want-to-return"

how to remove multi "--" to "-" for write url
Sorry my english very bad

Comment: So you need a rewrite rule for use in .htaccess? Sorry, I was confused by the php-tag.

Comment: Do you need a php solution or a htaccess example?

Comment: Not clear whether PHP solution is needed or .htaccess one. Have given answer for both but you better clarify.

Answer (score 5):

```
$string = 'over-80---of-international----visitors-want-to-return';
$string = preg_replace('#-{2,}#', '-', $string);
```

Comment: This solution does not work, it only removes one dash per multi-dash-group. You will sill be left with to many dashes!

Comment: That is not true, this works. Try it out. RegEx is greedy by default and only min is given by 2, so it will do what it is supposed to.

Comment: Oh, you are right, this makes your answer even perform better than mine. Sorry for my mistake, I changed my vote!

Answer (score 1):

preg_replace should work:

```
$s = preg_replace('/-{2,}/', '-', "over-80---of-international----visitors-want-to-return");
```

However if indeed OP is looking for mod_rewrite rule in .htaccess then this will work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(-)-+(.*)$ /$1$2$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$new = 'over-80---of-international----visitors-want-to-return';

do {
    $old = $new;
    $new = str_replace('--', '-', $old);
} while($old != $new);
```

This loop changes -- to - until there is nothing left to do.

Comment: he need rewrite rule using .htaccess file

Comment: Woops, I overlooked that. Sorry. But the question could be a little clearer, as everyone right now pops up with a php solution. Why does this question have a php-tag anyway?

Comment: thanks u every one. it hope very much

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [str-replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$string = "over-80---of-international----visitors-want-to-return";
$replaced = str_replace("--", "-", $string);
```

Comment: htaccess file code is needed

Comment: the question does not mention anything about an htaccess file.

Comment: Additionally, your solution does not remove every superfluous dash!

Comment: but he is asking for rewrite url which means htaccess

Comment: So is there a way to do this in .htaccess. And where is this string, in the query or in the path? He gave us a string, not an url, so we worked with that.

Comment: @LarsEbert, check the php manual link I give. you do *not* need to use the while loop.

Comment: @TusharGupta, indeed you are right, my bad.

Comment: Okay, it replaces multiple occurrences of the -- but if you have someting like ----, it replaces the first pair of dashes with - and the second pair of dashes with - and then you still have two dashes! str_replace does not look back after replacing. This is why you have to use the loop!